# JWT must be provided - Delete method returning token as null instead of user token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, http-delete

I have issue as title say. I will show you code in NodeJS. Request is blogRouter.delete

controllers/blog.js  (only delete method)

```
    const blogsRouter = require('express').Router()
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const Blog = require('../models/blog')
    const User = require('../models/user')

    blogsRouter.delete('/:id', async (request, response, next) => {

      const token = getTokenFrom(request)
      console.log('token: ',token)

      try {
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)

        if (!token || !decodedToken.id) {
          return response.status(401).json({ error: 'token missing or invalid' })
        }
        const userid = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
        const blogs = await Blog.findById(request.params.id)

        if(blogs.user.toString() === userid.toString()) {
          await Blog.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id)
          response.status(204).end()
        } else {
          response.status(404).end()
        }
      }catch(exception){next(exception)}  
    })
```

When i console log token i get null via helper function getTokenFrom

getTokenFrom

```
const getTokenFrom = request => {
  const authorization = request.get('authorization')
  if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
    return authorization.substring(7)
  }
  return null
}
```

In post request token working perfectly fine. Im able to create a blog. But when i do the same thing with delete method it wont show token. It says its **null**. So it returning me my getTokenFrom function correctly but i want to be able to access token in delete method so i can be able to delete certain blog.

controller/login

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const loginRouter = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/user')


loginRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body

    const user = await User.findOne({username: body.username})
    const passwordCorrect = user == null ? 
    false : await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.passwordHash)

    if(!(user && passwordCorrect)) {
        return response.status(401).json({
            error: "Invalid username or passowrd"
        })
    }

    const userForToken = {
        username: user.username,
        id: user._id,
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(userForToken, process.env.SECRET)

    response.status(200).send({token, username: user.username, name: user.name})
})

module.exports = loginRouter
```

https://prnt.sc/qfjgka --> This is a picture. I send http.delete request and i get token null. JWT must be provided. I dont know were is my mistake. I tried a lot of things but it wont work. 
I tried to define token with token.request.jwt but then i get it undifined.

I just need to access that token somehow in blogRoute.delete method.

Thanks in forward

EDIT : This is my post method and when i console log token here it returns me value of the token but when i do same things in delete method it wont work

```
blogsRouter.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {

  const body = request.body
  console.log('body', body)
  const token = getTokenFrom(request)
  console.log('token: ', token)

  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
    if (!token || !decodedToken.id) {
      return response.status(401).json({ error: 'token missing or invalid' })
    }

  const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)


  const blog = new Blog({
    title: body.title,
    author: body.author,
    url: body.url,
    likes: body.likes,
    user: user._id
  })


    const savedBlog = await blog.save()
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id)
    await user.save()
    response.json(savedBlog.toJSON())
  } catch(exception) {
    next(exception)
  }
})
```

Comment: And are you including the JWT token in the headers of the DELETE request? Given the token is passed down as part of the login request as part of the body and not a cookie, this will need to be manually done.

Comment: Im including it via this function const getTokenFrom = request => {
  const authorization = request.get('authorization')
  if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
    return authorization.substring(7)
  }
  return null
}

Comment: But it returns null instead of token

Comment: In delete request, are you sending the token same as in post request? Can you show the request headers in your delete request?

Comment: How to show request headers?

Comment: Click the data  -> headers in the browser console log

Comment: I edited post..Check post method that i showed u. Almost the same and i get the token from it but when i do the same in delete method i get null

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qfjtsq  -- this is in headers

Comment: Hmm, this looks like response headers, can you log request headers?

Comment: When i lost request.headers i get this on backend server https://prnt.sc/qfjv60

Comment: Somehow i need to get token. Im not autorized to delete without token. If i delete token code everthing works fine but i can delete all blog posts and I want to restrict that only user who made a blog can delete blog. Problem is that im constantly getting NULL when i try to define token variable

Comment: @VeljkoKukic  this type of token checking in every route is not good. Do you want a better solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204833/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-veljko-kukic).

Comment: @VeljkoKukic you need to be including the Authorization token in the DELETE request sent from the client, are you doing this? Show the client code you use to send the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the screenshot where you logged the request headers, there seems no authorization header, so you are getting error. If you can succesfully be able to send the authorization header, the problem will be resolved.

By the way, checking the token and validating it in every route is not a good solution.

You had better to use an authentication middleware for token validation.

1-) Create an auth middleware like this:

middleware\auth.js

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  } 

  if (!token) {
     return res.status(401).json({ error: 'token missing' })
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'token invalid' })
  }
};
```

2-) use this auth middlware anywhere you need authentication. Now our routes are clenaer and shorter.

```js
const blogsRouter = require("express").Router();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const User = require("../models/user");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

blogsRouter.delete("/:id", auth, async (request, response, next) => {
  try {

    const userid = request.user.id;    //we set the user in the auth middleware, so we can access it like this
    const blogs = await Blog.findById(request.params.id);

    if (blogs.user.toString() === userid.toString()) {
      await Blog.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id);
      response.status(204).end();
    } else {
      response.status(404).end();
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    next(exception);
  }
});

blogsRouter.post("/", auth, async (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    const body = request.body
    const user = await User.findById(request.user.id);

    const blog = new Blog({
      title: body.title,
      author: body.author,
      url: body.url,
      likes: body.likes,
      user: user._id
    });

    const savedBlog = await blog.save();
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id);
    await user.save();
    response.json(savedBlog.toJSON());
  } catch (exception) {
    next(exception);
  }
});
```

In this way you can send your token in the authorization header in the form  `Bearer  TOKEN.....`

Comment: ty for reply ill try this later.

Comment: @VeljkoKukic I hope you like this refactoring, this is the way we check authentication. If you send the token in the authorization header with correct format (Bearer ....)  it must work.

Comment: I wonder why this answer downvoted without any comment.  Is it bad to advise a better solution with the possible problem?

Comment: I didnt downvoted it ../. im gonna check it later mate and see if ur solution works. Ill aprove it :)

Comment: @VeljkoKukic I didn't say to you:) someone made it, but didn't give any comment:)

Comment: Even if i do this as u said i get error from ur middleware/auth - token missing. jwt must be provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204871/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-veljko-kukic).

Answer (score 0):

" if (blogs.user.toString() === userid.toString()) {"  it is important to restrict user access to his own resources, so that the route is something like:
delete posts/:id
rather than, delete /users/:uid/posts/:id because hackers will be able to guess out the ids and delete other people's posts.